# Elasticsearch - How to refresh the data in http://<host>:port/heartbeat-*/_search?pretty

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana

After adding new ping url's to the heartbeat config for my Kibana  service, I can see all the URL's in "Uptime" but they are not reflected in:

> `http://<host>:port/heartbeat-*/_search?pretty`

.

Can anyone tell me how I can refresh / update that data? Preferably using the elasticsearch GUI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `http://<host>:port/heartbeat-*/_refresh?pretty`

Reference: [Refresh API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html)

If you find latest data is still not loading, you can refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/heartbeat/current/heartbeat-template.html#force-kibana-new) and delete existing `heartbeat` indices using `curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/heartbeat-*'`. Note that this will `DELETE` all your  `heartbeat-*` indices. However, new data should appear pretty soon in it.

Comment: {
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "request [/heartbeat-*/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [refresh]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "request [/heartbeat-*/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [refresh]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}

Comment: @Scouse_Bob I have edited the post to fix the typo.

Comment: Thanks, it still doesn't reflect the URL's that come up in "uptime" though once I run your command. So, still scratching my head on this one :-/ the output from your command is below

Comment: {
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  }
}

Comment: When you run the command it refreshes the data in index immediately allowing you to see the latest data.

Comment: All of the data in the http://<host>:port/heartbeat-*/_search?pretty url reflects what I am monitoring in heartbeat, with the exception of one server, which is missing. I thought that must be because some refresh process is not happening... it all looks fine in "uptime" but it's not shown under http://<host>:port/heartbeat-*/_search?pretty I thought it should be... do you know how I can get it there? Nothing I have done so far is successful

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24413924)

Comment: Thanks @NikolayShevchenko. Noted your point. From the ask `Can anyone tell me how I can refresh / update that data`, since the ask was to `refresh` the data, I answered it as using `_refresh` API